# LaTeX display math alignment in Anki

Tags: latex, anki

I've been trying to create mathematics flashcards in [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/). Naturally, I wanted [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) to be the default typesetting system for those cards. In order to do so, I created a new basic note type named *basic math*. Here's my options header:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in, paperheight=100in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,mathrsfs,color}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
\renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
\begin{document}
```

My card type front (in French) is:

> [latex]{{Recto}}[/latex]

My card type back (in French) is:

```
{{FrontSide}}

<hr id=answer>
<br />

[latex]{{Verso}}[/latex]
```

Finally, here's my card type style:

```
.card {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
background-color: white;
}
img {
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-height:1000px;
}
```

Here's a card front (in French):

```
Vrai ou faux ?
\[
z-\overline{z}=2\Im z
\]
```

and its back:

```
Faux. En général,
\[
z-\overline{z}=2{\color{red}i}\Im z
\]
```

Alas, here's the rendering:

[image]

Clearly, something's weird with the alignment of the display math. If I change the back of the card for this:

```
Faux. En général, bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\[
z-\overline{z}=2{\color{red}i}\Im z
\]
```

then the equation is properly centered (as it should normally be by default with LaTeX):

[image]

So, my question is: **How to get the proper center alignment, as the Anki math environment [$$][/$$] would give?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you Can't Do™ what you're trying to do with `[latex]{{Recto}}[/latex]`. I refer you [to the manual](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#media-&-latex-references):

> Media references to fields are not allowed. They may or may not display during review, and will not work when checking for unused media, importing/exporting, and so on. Examples that won’t work:
>
> ```
> [latex]{{Field 1}}[/latex]
> ```

---

Besides that, though, what you're seeing is a result of the `\documentclass{article}`, combined with how Anki invokes `dvipng` to *crop* the resulting image. (Also, why the heck do you have it set to `100in`? )

Let's take a look what's happening behind the scenes, when Anki generates an image from LaTeX:

1. `latex` (*not* `pdflatex`! the old-school one, unless you're manually changing `anki.latex.latexCmds` with an add-on.) is invoked, to generate a DVI file from the concatenated LaTeX input:

   ```
    latex -interaction=nonstopmode tmp.tex
   ```
2. `dvipng` is invoked on the result, to convert it to a PNG that can be included into your Anki deck, and in the process, crops out most of the whitespace:

   ```
    dvipng -D 400 -T tight tmp.dvi -o tmp.png
   ```

---

Okay, let's see this in action on your “working” example, minus the ultra-tall `100in` instruction (click the image to see it full-size):

[image]

Bottom-left is your concatenated LaTeX code; top-right is the document generated by LaTeX; and bottom-right is the final, cropped image.

**So far, so good.** Let's try your *original* code:

[image]

### Ahhah! Do you see what's happening, there?

Your equation **is** centered, from LaTeX's perspective — that is, the perspective of a `5in`-wide `{article}`, which is what you have herein told it to generate; it's the *cropping* that's making it look like it's ofw-center. (Or, from another perspective, we could say that the equation is centered, and it's the *text* that's being payed-out poorly — it's offset *far to the left*, in your document.)

---

Okay, enough of the “why.” Unfortunately, as far as I know, this is not an easy problem to fix, and still get out what Anki expects.

One approach, though, that *will work*, with your specific example, is to switch from a standard `\documentclass{article}`, to [`\documentclass{standalone}`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/standalone/standalone.pdf) — a package with a feature specifically designed to do what we want to do, here (adjust the *layout* — stuff like your centering, for instance — within LaTeX, to typeset things to their smallest size.)

Specifically, let's try the `crop` and `varwidth` options. Change your LaTeX prelude in Anki to the following, adjusted as necessary¹ to your needs: (notice that I've gotten rid of Anki's default `\special{papersize=3in,5in}` line, as it's no longer relevant)

```
\documentclass[crop=true,varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
```

[image]

### Tada!

**Now, let's talk about caveats**, before I ride off into the SRS sunset:

1. This is going to cause some compilation errors. Don't ask me why — I think the `standalone` package doesn't like what we're doing with it (it's built to generate its *own* images? Although I'm not sure of the specifics.) This shouldn't screw up Anki's image generation, tho they might show up in the preview window for you, I'm not sure? YMMV.
2. `varwidth` environments have … many caveats. A bunch of things don't work in them. I don't know all of the details — you'll [have to go trawling through TeX.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bstandalone%5d%20varwidth) to find answers from people more knowledgable than I, most likely, when using it.

Because of those, I want to examine one last alternative:

## Don't typeset your entire card in LaTeX *in the first place*!

It's lucky we're on SuperUser, and not TeX.se — I'm pretty sure it's Highest Blasphemy over there, but quite honestly, Computer Modern is Effing Ugly on screens *anyway* (it's designed for print, and it's great there … but not so much on screens, which is where we use Anki); and more relevantly, Anki is [likely to move to MathJax](https://github.com/dae/anki/pull/107#issuecomment-128987122) in the future (i.e. more consistent in-card rendering, as opposed to shipping around hacky pre-compiled PNGs like this.) It's more future-proof to rely on Anki's built-in web engine (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) for styling and typesetting, than to ship that all out to LaTeX! Rendering equations to PNGs using LaTeX is effectively, at this point, a hold-over measure.

Basically, this can all be avoided, if you just typeset your card in HTML. Instead of:

```
[latex]
Faux. En général,
\[
z-\overline{z}=2{\color{red}i}\Im z
\]
[/latex]
```

… try:

```
Faux. En général,
[$$]z-\overline{z}=2{\color{red}i}\Im z[/$$]
```

[image]

Boom; the text is centered over the equation. What a masterpiece! (My settings are slightly different than yours; yours won't be so outsized-looking, etc.)

---

1. I have no idea how to make the `{geometry}` package you use work with `{standalone}`. I'm not actually an expert, I just happened to grapple with this specific problem a while back — getting it to work with *your specific needs*, will probably need some wrangling with LaTeX itself, as opposed to Anki. Good luck.

Comment: (P.S. — I've flagged this to be moved to [TeX.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com), as that's probably a more appropriate venue for such questions!)